# Nextjs render a new div onClick

Tags: javascript, next.js

I have an image and I want to create a new div (on click) with a larger version of the same image.

I've tried four approaches:

1. Render div on Click

```
function zoom_img (event) {
    console.log(event.target);
    console.log(event.target['data-loaded-src'])
    const src = event.target['data-loaded-src']
    
    return (
      <div className='w-screen h-screen fixed flex justify-center items-center'>
        <div className='w-9/12 h-5/6 bg-slate-200 opacity-50'>
          <Image src={src} fill={true} />
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }

...

<Image src={'/gafas.png'} width={150} height={150} alt='Gafas 1' onClick={zoom_img}/>
```

2. Custom component

```
function Glasses ({src, height, width, alt}) {
    function enlrg() {
      console.log(src);
      return (
        <div className='w-screen h-screen fixed flex justify-center items-center'>
          <div className='w-9/12 h-5/6 bg-slate-200 opacity-50'>
            <Image src={src} fill={true} />
          </div>
        </div>
      )
    }
    return (
      <Image src={src} width={width} height={height} alt={alt} onClick={enlrg} />
    )
  }


...

<Glasses src={'/gafas.png'} width={150} height={150} alt='Gafas 1' />
```

3. Existing div onClick remove hidden class

```
function Glasses2 ({src, height, width, alt}) {
    function enlrg() {
      console.log(src);
      let x = document.getElementById('temp');
      x.classList.remove('hidden');
      x.classList.add('flex');
    }
    return (
      <Image src={src} width={width} height={height} alt={alt} onClick={enlrg} />
    )
  }


...

<Glasses2 src={'/gafas.png'} width={150} height={150} alt='Gafas 1' />
<div id='temp' className='w-screen h-screen fixed hidden justify-center items-center'>
  <div className='w-9/12 h-5/6 bg-slate-200 opacity-50'>
    <Image src={'/gafas.png'} fill={true} />
  </div>
</div>
```

4. This one DID work but I'm loosing nextjs image optimization

```
function zoom_img (event) {
    console.log(event.target);
    console.log(event.target['data-loaded-src'])
    const src = event.target['data-loaded-src']
    const new_cont = document.createElement('div');
    const new_div = document.createElement('div');
    const main = document.getElementById('main');
    new_cont.classList.add('w-screen', 'h-screen', 'fixed', 'flex', 'justify-center', 'items-center');
    new_div.classList.add('w-9/12', 'h-5/6', 'bg-slate-200', 'opacity-50');
    // add img tag here
    new_cont.appendChild(new_div);
    main.appendChild(new_cont);
  }


...

<Image src={'/gafas.png'} width={150} height={150} alt='Gafas 1' onClick={zoom_img} />
```

In every approach I DO get to see the log in the console but only in approach 4 I see the new div.

Is approach 4 the only correct way? I would prefer to use the Image component if possible. What do you guys think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

Set the hook:

```
[zoomImage, setZoomImage] = useState(false)
```

```js
<Image src={'/gafas.png'} width={150} height={150} alt='Gafas 1' onClick={() => setZoomImage(true)}/>

// zoomed image
<div className={`${zoomImage ? 'block' : 'hidden'} w-screen h-screen fixed flex justify-center items-center`}>
<div className='w-9/12 h-5/6 bg-slate-200 opacity-50'>
   <Image src={src} fill={true} />
</div>
</div>
```

In this code you are actually telling Next.JS that whenever user clicks that image, change variable `zoomImage` to true and as a result that bigger image that is hidden by default, will have display block. (I supposed you're using tailwindcss)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much @Atena Dadkhah. Your answer worked perfectly.

In the project a have not one but a bunch of images so the final code looked like this:

```
function enlarge(e) {
    setLrg(true);
    let img = document.getElementById('largerImage'),
        src = e.target['data-loaded-src'];
    img['src'] = src;
  }
```

Then a bunch of images like this:

```
<Image src={'/gafas.png'} width={150} height={150} alt='Gafas 1' onClick={enlarge} className='cursor-zoom-in' />
```

Then the hidden div:

```
<div className={`${lrg ? 'flex' : 'hidden'} w-screen h-screen fixed justify-center items-center`}>
  <div className='w-9/12 h-5/6 bg-slate-200 flex justify-center items-center relative'>
    <Image id='largerImage' fill={true} />
  </div>
</div>
```

It's still missing the behaviour for closing the div but that should be easy to add.

Once again. Thank you :)